# Flex remoting and progress events?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, remoting, amf

Is there a way to monitor the loading progress (percent progress bar style) when using Flex remoting?

I'm trying out Flash Builder 4 with it's new data services features, but I can't find any pgrogress event stuff somewhere. This article by Robert Taylor http://www.roboncode.com/articles/144 indicates that it might not be possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not do that..when calling a remote method you launch an HTTP POST call containing the AMF message (serialized input parameters and the destination/method name) and on response you receive the AMF response. There is no way to tell you the progress and the workaround implies a lot of work (you will have to create a socket and build your mini protocol on top of AMF).

Comment: Thank you, Cornel! That's a pity... It makes the remoting solution not suitable for handling larger chunks of data. The Robert Taylor solution http/UrlLoader solution works fine, but then you loose the excellent Flash Builder 4 data service functionality...

Comment: Welcome. Do you really have such a large amount of data? Maybe you can use different approaches - pagination, background loading, lazy loading, zip compression?